# Passing a temporary to a function as an lvalue

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a list class as follows

```
class NOlist { // "Non-Owning" list

protected:

    int nData;
    double* data;

    // Construct given an existing data array
    NOlist(int nDataArg, double* dataArg) : nData(nDataArg), data(dataArg) {}

public:

    // Copy constructor
    NOlist(const NOlist&)=default;

    // Return NOlist representing sub-list 
    NOlist subList(const int at) {
        return NOlist(nData-at, data+at);
    }

    // Operators
    NOlist& operator*=(const double& factor) {
        for(int i = 0; i < nData; i++) {
            data[i] *= factor;
        }
        return *this;
    }

};

struct List : public NOlist { // Wrapper (responsible for memory management only)

    List(const int nDataArg) : NOlist(nDataArg, new double[nDataArg]) {}

    ~List() { delete[] data; }

};

void triple(NOlist& arg) {
     arg *= 3.0;
}
```

I like this pattern because it makes it possible to things like `A.subList(1).subList(2)`, which makes it convenient to implement some things recursively. My actual case is more complicated, but I've stripped it down to something which represents the core idea.

This creates a problem in the following

```
List A(50);

// [code to set A...]

A.subList(5) *= 3; // works 
triple(A.subList(5)); // error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'NOlist&' from an rvalue of type 'NOlist'
```

My guess is that, in the second-last line, `A.subList(5)` is `this` during the call to `operator*=` and is therefore guaranteed to last for the entire call, but in the second case it is just an argument and therefore its lifetime gets no extension. I can get around the error by replacing the last line with

```
NOlist Atmp(A.subList(5)); // make the subList non-temporary
triple(Atmp);              // modify the subList
```

...but I'm wondering whether there is a more elegant solution. Essentially I would like to prolong the life of a temporary for the duration of a function call and allow it to be used as an lvalue during that lifespan.

Comment: As you seem to be using C++11, just change the signature to `void triple(NOlist&& arg)`. I don't see the point of modifying a temporary and dropping it afterwards, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume your function triple takes a reference. If you make it take the parameter by-value, it will just work (equivalent to the code you wrote as a workaround) but it won't require you to manually create the temporary object (instead, it will be created at function-call time.)

Assuming your `NOlist` is cheap to create/copy, that's a valid solution. Alternatively, you could have a special proxy type just for that use case.